# Missing gconf/gconf-client.h

Tags: ubuntu, notification-area, evolution, gconf

I'm trying to install an Evolution plugin using these instructions:

[How do I minimize Evolution to the system tray in Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/112210/how-do-i-minimize-evolution-to-the-system-tray-in-ubuntu)

In the `sudo make` stage, I get the following output:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gilnaa/Downloads/evolution-tray-0.0.8'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gilnaa/Downloads/evolution-tray-0.0.8/src'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gilnaa/Downloads/evolution-tray-0.0.8/src'
  CC     tray.lo
tray.c:28:32: fatal error: gconf/gconf-client.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [tray.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gilnaa/Downloads/evolution-tray-0.0.8/src'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gilnaa/Downloads/evolution-tray-0.0.8/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gilnaa/Downloads/evolution-tray-0.0.8'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

See the following line:

```
tray.c:28:32: fatal error: gconf/gconf-client.h: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This means that you need to install the C header files (aka development library) for gconf.  Try installing the package `libgconf2-dev`, then try again.